# WiFi Access point switch android

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I have two access point broadcasting same SSID across a wide open area. Usually the mobile device switches to strongest AP by default if the currently AP is not strong enough without haviong disconnecting and reconnecting to WiFi. But over a long period we have observed that the WiFi switching does not happen sometimes.

For such cases we were planning to handle that switching at android application level itself. 
But after doing lots of research over web. We could only find methods which involve disconnecting the Wifi and reconnecting again which is not desirable in our case. As our application accepts payments over web . Disconnecting and reconnecting again based on signal strength would result in payments getting declined.

Is is possible to replicate the WiFi switching which mobile device does automatically at android application level.(I know the question is absurd but i am desperately looking for a workaround)